# Elixir function /number syntax

Tags: function, elixir

New to Elixir, trying to understand what this syntax means:

`MyApplication.Module.function/2`

What does the number after the function represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Elixir and Erlang functions can have multiple body clauses (in contrast to C++, Java etc.), so to distinguish we use **arity**, where it's simply *number of arguments*.

For example:

```
defmodule Math do

  def sum(x) do
    x + 0
  end

  def sum(x, y) do
    x + y
  end
end
```

So in this you have two similar yet different functions: `sum/1` and `sum/2`.

Quite often you can see that the function with larger number of arguments is used internally to calculcate the result.

Answer (score 4):

The number represents the arity of the function. This syntax is used when you want to pass a named function to functions that take a function as an argument. It is real handy for things like

```
"1 2 3" |> String.split(" ") |> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1)
```

Comment: added note: 'arity' means 'the number of arguments a function takes'.